# Javascript: How to get array of strings of text within p tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Lets say I have string with a lot of p tags in it...

```
var myString = "<p>Some text.</p><p>Some more. Some more text.</p><p>And even some more text.</p>";
```

..how do I get an array, each item in the array is a string of text that was in the p tags:

```
 [
    "Some text.",
    "Some more. Some more text.",
    "And even some more text."
]
```

One way I suppose would be to get rid of the p tags...

```
   var stringWithOutTags = myString.replace(/(<p>|<\/p>)/g, " ");
```

..And then use .split() to get out each sentence. But I don't really want to get out each sentence, just text w.in p tags

```
var stringAsArray = stringWithOutTags.split(".");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the <p> tags from your string and split using the closing </p> tag only to get the desired result.

```
myString.replace('<p>', '').split('</p>');
```

Comment: please add some description to the code in the answer.

Comment: Good idea, because it's SSR save. Personally I would prefer to go with the "global" approach: myString.replace(/<p>/g, '').split('</p>')

Answer (score 3):

If you are executing the code on browser, you can parse the string as HTML instead of using regular expression:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = myString;
var texts = [].map.call(el.querySelectorAll('p'), function(p) {
   return p.textContent;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not split after you replace:

```
var a = "<p>Some text.</p><p>Some more. Some more text.</p><p>And even some more text.</p>";

var b = a.replace(/(<p>|<\/p>)/g, " ").split('  ');
```

https://jsbin.com/wopute/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

**Note: please only use this method if you are sure that you can trust the input string (i.e. it is not user input)!**

```
var myString = "<p>Some text.</p><p>Some more. Some more text.</p><p>And even some more text.</p>";

// Create a "div" element
var div = document.createElement("div");

// Get browser to parse string, and set the parsed HTML elements as
// the contents of the div element
div.innerHTML = myString;

// Loop over the child elements of the div, and return an array of
// the textual content the elements. If you wish to preserve tags
// inside the <p> elements, replace .textContent with .innerHTML
var arrayOfStrings = Array.prototype.map.call(div.childNodes, function (pTag) {
    return pTag.textContent;
});
```

Comment: Great point, if the input is a user-input, then the string should not be html-parsed, at least not in this optimistic way. My answer doesn't mention security concerns involved in this approach.